# Rescind 'find my device' location permission in Google account

Tags: privacy, location-services

I had lost my phone somewhere in the same room I was in. To make it ring in Google's find my phone feature, I had to give it full permission to process it's location data. How do I rescind these permissions?

Answer (score 0):

On your device, go to your Google services and preferences found in your device settings, and under Find My Device toggle the option off.  For the device-level, you will want to go to App Permissions and toggle off location permissions for the Find My Device application, then also disable it as a Device Administrator app from your Security settings.  This should disable both app-based and browser-based permissions for the device to be pinged.

Comment: This completely disables find my device. I don't want that. This is definitely a Google account level setting, as I could enable it without having physical access to the phone.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your post then.  However, in that case, just disregard the first sentence and follow the latter portion of my answer, that should take care of the device-level permissions.

Comment: Actually upon re-reading your OP, I'm realizing I don't understand what your inquiry is lol.  Can you please explain with more detail what exactly you're trying to accomplish?